# Excel - how to get value from another cell if matches criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, search

Could I ask for some help with Excel formula? I tried different formulas with IF, SEARCH and VLOOKUP but it didn't give results that I wanted.

What I try to do is to get value from other table on the same sheet if it matches criteria.

I want to get information - If C2 equals "TRUE", search column F for "**", and put in value in column G in the same line to D2. But I can't have them repeating, so if there if there is second value in column C which also says "TRUE" I need different value from column G.

I am attaching two screenshots. One that doesn't have information in column D:
[image: Screenshot]

... and a second one that shows how it should look at the end:
[image: Filled table]

Comment: It would help clarify your problem if you filled out column D in your example, at least partly. I'm guessing that since you have five items in green and five ** in blue that you want them to match up accordingly. Is that correct? (e.g. cell D2:D6 will end up with the value from cells G3, G5, G6, G7, G9 respectively)

Comment: Hi, thank you for coming back to me. I have attached second screenshot to post, showing how i would like it to look at the end. Only rows that have TRUE in column C needs filling with data. Ones with FALSE ideally should be either blank or having n/a in them.

Comment: Fill it down in order by table 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Office 365, you can use:

```
=IF(C2=FALSE,"",INDEX(FILTER(pfLookup[PF],pfLookup[Sku]="**"),COUNTIF($C$2:C2,TRUE)))
```

The lookup table I made into a **Table** and named it `pfLookup`

[image]

If you do not have the `FILTER` function, you can use:

```
=IF(C2=FALSE,"",
           INDEX(pfLookup[PF],
               INDEX(
                     AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(pfLookup[Sku]="**")*ROW(pfLookup),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTIF(pfLookup[Sku],"~*~*"))))-ROW(pfLookup[#Headers]),
                     COUNTIF($C$2:C2,TRUE),1)))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you :) It works perfectly

Comment: @Martyna Glad to help. Since my answer seems to be what you require, kindly mark it as Accepted.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: it has been done now. Thank you again.